# Are all predatory animals forbidden to eat?

Tags: halal-haram, fiqh, food, meat

Surprisingly I did not find this question already posted on this site.

Is it true all such animals that eat other animals are forbidden to eat? I have been hearing this doctrine my whole life from my mosque and family so I tried to look for the evidence but did not find it and the closest I got was:

> Allah's Messenger (صلى الله عليه وسلم) prohibited the eating of all fanged beasts of prey 
> **[ [Sunnah Ref: Sahih Muslim 1934a](https://sunnah.com/muslim:1934a) ]**

but is there an evidence that all beasts of prey / carnivores / predators are forbidden to eat?

Comment: What you heard was probably a shortening of the actual hadith which specifies "fanged." The classification of carnivore is obviously modern. As for predators, we eat many of them. For example, chicken.

Answer (score 1):

All beasts of prey that have (large) teeth are forbidden. This concerns essentially mammals and reptiles; from the latter only snakes are mentioned explicitly.

Birds with talons also fall into the category of forbidden predators whereas birds that eat insects are not forbidden.

Fish and whales are not understood in this category even if they have large teeth and eat meat.

In this sense, many but not all predators are forbidden.